# How to Convert List<user> to List<object>

Tags: asp.net

I have list  of user class but now i have to return it as a list of object, I try to convert it but it gives me error like. Can not implicitly convert.

Comment: Why do you need to convert the list to a list of objects?

Comment: @msarchet: probably to satisfy a third party library API requirement. It happens to me unfortunately rather frequently.

Comment: because my function return type if list<object>

Answer (score 7):

The simplest solution in .NET 3.5 would be:

```
List<object> objects = users.Cast<object>().ToList();
```

Note that this will create a *copy* of the list. You can't view a `List<User>` as a `List<object>` - otherwise you'd be able to do:

```
objects.Add(new SomeOtherType());
```

which would clearly break things.

In C# 4, you can use the covariance of `IEnumerable<T>` to make it slightly simpler:

```
List<object> objects = new List<object>(users);
```

or

```
List<object> objects = users.ToList<object>();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public List<Object> ConvertToObjectList<N>(List<N> sourceList)
{
    List<Object> result = new List<Object>();

    foreach(N item in sourceList)
    {
        result.Add(item as Object);
    }

    return result;
}

...

List<Object> myList = ConvertToObjectList<myClass>(myOldList);
```

I am not sure if I understood your question correctly, but here's my two cents.

Answer (score 0):

=/ with linq?

```
var object_list = from o in user_list
                  select new {
                      User: o.User,
                      Guid: o.Guid
                      // insert properties here
                  }
```

??????

Comment: That returns an IEnumerable<Anonymous_Type`1>